# modal ajax php multiples registros

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

tengo un proyecto con php puro de un sistema de tickets, tengo una ventana en donde por una tabla se pintan los tickets activos por usuario asi

```html
<?php if ($tikets != "No hay tikets") {
    foreach ($tikets as $tkt) { ?>

     <tr>
      <td><a href="detalle.php?tk=<?= $tkt['id_tiket'] ?>"><?= $tkt['id_tiket'] ?></a></td>
      <td><?= $tkt['asunto'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $tkt['descripcion'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $tkt['fecha'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $tkt['nombre'] ?></td>

      <?php if ($_SESSION['usuario'] == "admin") { ?>

       <td><?= $tkt['estado'] ?></td>
      <?php } else { ?>
       <td> <button asunto="<?= $tkt['asunto'] ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cerrarTicket" class="ticket btn btn-success btn-sm" data-id="<?= $tkt['id_tiket'] ?>"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Cerrar ticket</button>  </td>
      <?php } ?>
     </tr>
   <?php }
   } else {
    echo "<h1>No hay tickets</h1>";
   } ?>
  </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al dar click en el boton se despliega este modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="cerrarTicket" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
   
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Esta seguro de cerrar el ticket </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">volver</button>
                
                    <button type="submit" id="confirmar" class="btn btn-danger">Confirmar</button>
                

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tengo este js para manejar la data a enviar por ajax

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".ticket").forEach(ticket => ticket.addEventListener("click", function() {
    delete id;
    id = ticket.getAttribute("data-id");
    var asunto = ticket.getAttribute("asunto");


    $('#ModalLabel').append(asunto);
    
    $('.close').click(function() {
        $('#ModalLabel').empty();
    });
    $('#cerrarTicket').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#ModalLabel').empty();
    });

    $('#confirmar').click(function() {

        parametros = {
            "id": id,
        };

        console.log(parametros);

        var url = 'cerrarTicket.php';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data) {

                // console.log(data);
            }
        });


    });


}));
```

el problema es que cuando le doy al boton enviar del modal me envia todos los id de los tickets que yo haya seleccionado, si seleccione el id 1 y se envia manda bien la respuesta pero cuando le doy al boton del id 2 se envia la peticion ajax pero esta vez me envia el id 1 y 2 
agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Según entiendo el modal es únicamente como una confirmación previa a cerrar el ticket correcto?

Comment: Al evento del botón que envía el formulario prueba colocarle la función unbind, esto evitará que te envíe nuevamente los ids anteriores.

Comment: correcto amigo, muchas gracias.